# Why is there a difference in how the in operator behaves?

Tags: python, in-operator

This works perfectly

```py
def get_count(sentence):
        return sum(1 for letter in sentence if letter in ('aeiou'))
```

But when I apply the in operator to an array like this, it fails

```py
# Incorrect answer for "aeiou": 0 should equal 5
def get_count(sentence):
        return sum(1 for letter in sentence if letter in ['aeiou'])
```

Comment: One evaluates to a string, the other to a list. Take a look at `print(('aeiou'), ['aeiou'])`

Comment: `('aeiou')` is not a tuple

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet, `('aeiou')` is a string surrounded by parentheses (which have no syntactic function in this case). The `in` is applied to the string, which is itself an iterable, and thus checks if `letter` is one of the characters in that string.

In the second snippet, `['aeoiu']` is a list with a single element, the string `'aeiou'`. The `in` operator applies to the list, and checks if `letter` is one of the elements in the list. It obviously isn't (since `letter` is a single character), and thus this condition always evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

It's is not so much the behavior of `in` that's different, as the syntax being unexpected for beginners. `()` is an empty tuple. But that's the only time that parentheses make a tuple. In all other cases, parentheses are needed for grouping, but it's the comma that makes a tuple.

- `('aeiou')` is not a tuple. It's a string with superfluous parentheses. `('aeiou',)` is a tuple, and so is `'aeiou',`.
- `['aeiou']` is unambiguously a list with one element.

Letters are length-one strings in python: there are no character objects as such.

- In the first case, you are searching for each letter in a string, which is a container of length-one strings, so you occasionally find one.
- In the second case, you are searching for each letter in a list, which is a container of not-length-one strings, so you never find a match.

Compare the second case to `list('aeiou')`. Instead of making a list of one element as `['aeiou']`, this creates a list containing all the letters in the input string.

Unrelated fun fact: `sum` defaults to a starting value of `0` (the `int`), and `bool` is a subclass of `int` that always equals zero or one. You can therefore rewrite your counter in the following ways:

```
sum(letter in 'aeiou' for letter in sentence)
sum(map('aeiou'.__contains__, sentence))
```

Answer (score 2):

`('aeiou')` is a string. You can verify this with

```py
>>> x = ('aeiou')
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
```

`['aeiou']` on the other hand is a list containing one element which in turn is a string.

```py
>>> x = ['aeiou']
>>> type(x)
<class 'list'>
>>> len(x)
1
>>> type(x[0])
<class 'str'>
```

When you write `if letter in ('aeiou')`, here you are testing if the letter is a substring of the string `'aeiou'`. However, when you write `if letter in ['aeiou']`, you are testing if the letter is an element in the list the contains one element, the string `'aeiou'` which is always `False` for `letter` that is a single character.

Answer (score 1):

`('aeiou')` equals `'aeiou'`, brackets like this are redundant.

Second time you are looking if chars from your `sentence` are in `['aeiou']`. This list contains a string of 5 characters, so `letter in ['aeiou']` would never return `True`.